# Optimized solutions for my homework

Tags: c, optimization

A snail creeps x ft up a wall during the daytime. After all the labor it does throughout the day, it stops to rest a while... but falls asleep!! The next morning it wakes up and discovers that it has slipped down y ft while sleeping.

If this happens every day, how many times will the snail creep to cover n walls of different height?

I have written a function to count the number of creeps of the snail as shown below:

```
void count(int move_forward, int move_backward, int number_walls, int[] height)
    {
        int count = number_walls, diff = move_forward - move_backward;
        while (number_walls--)
            for (move_backward = move_forward; move_backward < height[number_walls]; move_backward += diff)
                count++;
    }
```

It's working fine.  But I wanted to know if there is any other way of solving this problem to optimize the speed of the program further.

Comment: (height-x)/(x-y)+1, no loops required

Comment: @Jay, BTW--The advice you received in the early question about using meaningful variable names is debatable in the context of inner loops. Too many, too long names make your code every bit as unreadable as a bunch of cryptic one and two letter names. It's all about balance.

Comment: One more comment as long as I'm sticking my nose in. The point of this exercise may be to show you that bit sitting and thinking for a while you can the problem of the individual walls from `O(height)` (the way you were trying it)  to `O(1)` (the way amit solves it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solution is `((height-x)/(x-y))+1`, no loops required.

the snail needs to climb to: `height-x`, and it takes him `((height-x)/(x-y))` days. Once it is there, it takes him an extra day to climb the remaining x.

**EDIT:** as mentioned in the comments, this solution solves the problem for each wall, you'll need to iterate over your `heights` array, and summarize these results, saving you at least the inner loop, making it O(n), instead O(n*h), where n is the number of walls, and h is the walls' heights.

(*)note: that you might want to save the reminder for each wall [i.e. how much the snail can keep going after he had passed this wall], and subtract it from the next wall, dependes on the task description... If the snail can pass a maximum of one wall per day, ignore this last comment.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess it's because height is an array of values. You'll still need a loop to either get the total height or apply the solution to each height.

Comment: @tinman: you are correct, this answer shows how to do it for a single wall, I'll mention it explicitly. thanks for the comment.

Comment: @amit..as per ur formula....suppose if a wall is of height 5 and snail can creep 4 and then slip down 1 ......((5-4)/(4-1))+1 which is 1.....but the solution should be 2 since during first creep he moves only 3 and will require another creep to climb the wall...

Comment: @Jay: you will need the `ceil` for the number of days [and not the usual `floor` for integers oparations], which is indeed 2 in your example. This solution is not a full answer, it just a hint to help you solve your homework by your own.

Comment: @amit ..and wat if the height is less than the x??

Comment: @Jay: a negative number of days is meaningless, in this case you should of course take 0 for `(height-x)/(x-y)`, which will get you an overall result of 1 of course. I think this assigment is ment to make you think about all these corner cases. As I said, this is not a complete answer, but if you work with this equation, and cover corner cases, you should get the best performance, as your question asks for.